# How do I find the resolution of a scale range from the Arcgis Server REST services?

Tags: arcgis-server, rest, arcgis-flex-api

What's the best way to determine a LOD's resolution from the esri REST API?

Currently, I make a request for a specific extent to the server from the flex api, and from that I divide the width of the image in pixels by the width of the map it represents in map units, but aside from feeling like a bit of a hack, it has trouble when dealing with services that are represented in degrees rather than meters.

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with cached maps, the /MapServer REST call returns TileInfo information, which includes information about each LOD and its resolution.